# Focus on input to display backdrop div with CSS selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, shopify

I am trying to display div.search-backdrop when a visitor puts the cursor in search field #Search-In-Modal-1 using input:focus, but I am having a really hard time writing the proper css selector for this. I sometimes get confused by using +, > or ~ but I thought it should work like this...

Code snippet from Shopify:

```
                <div class="search-modal__container">
                    <predictive-search class="search-modal__form" data-loading-text="Loading...">
                        <form action="/en/search" method="get" role="search" class="search search-modal__form">
                            <div class="field">
                                <input class="search__input field__input" id="Search-In-Modal-1" type="search" name="q" value="" placeholder="Search" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="predictive-search-results-list" aria-controls="predictive-search-results-list" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-autocomplete="list" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false">
                                <label class="field__label" for="Search-In-Modal-1">Search</label>
                                <input type="hidden" name="options[prefix]" value="last">
                                <button class="search__button field__button" aria-label="Search">
                                    <!--<svg class="icon icon-search" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation">
                                                  <use href="#icon-search">
                                                </svg>-->
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="icon icon-search">
                                        <path d="M22.938 13.382c-0.036 5.247-4.318 9.472-9.565 9.437s-9.472-4.318-9.436-9.565c0.035-5.223 4.28-9.438 9.503-9.437 5.263 0.023 9.513 4.302 9.501 9.565h-0.003zM26.881 13.382c-0.032-7.423-6.075-13.414-13.498-13.382s-13.414 6.075-13.382 13.497c0.031 7.4 6.039 13.382 13.44 13.382 7.435-0.025 13.447-6.062 13.44-13.498z"></path>
                                        <path d="M29.216 31.882l-8.499-8.451 2.784-2.787 8.499 8.451-2.784 2.787z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="predictive-search predictive-search--header" tabindex="-1" data-predictive-search>
                                <div class="predictive-search__loading-state">
                                    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="spinner" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                        <circle class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="6" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle>
                                    </svg>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <span class="predictive-search-status visually-hidden" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </form>
                    </predictive-search>
                </div>
                <div class="search-backdrop"></div>
```

The CSS I have tried:

```
div.search-backdrop {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(var(--color-foreground),.2);
    backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: none;
  }
input#Search-In-Modal-1:focus ~ #shopify-section-header > sticky-header > header.header.header--top-left.page-width.header--has-menu > div.search-backdrop {
  display: block;
}
```

Please can somebody enlighten me why it is not working?

I have gotten the CSS selector path from the browser developer-menu, hoping it would be easy as that, but I am probably missing something crucial...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: TLDR: `.search-modal__container:focus-within + .search-backdrop {}` or, more specific yet less browser-compatible, `.search-modal__container:has(#Search-In-Modal-1:focus) + .search-backdrop {}`.

Comment: Yes! Thanks, that works beautifully. Can you enlighten me where I went wrong? And what sorcery is this ' :focus-within + '?

Comment: See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```css
div.search-backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(var(--color-foreground),.2);
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
}

.search-modal__container:has(#Search-In-Modal-1:focus-visible) + .search-backdrop {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-modal__container">
                    <predictive-search class="search-modal__form" data-loading-text="Loading...">
                        <form action="/en/search" method="get" role="search" class="search search-modal__form">
                            <div class="field">
                                <input class="search__input field__input" id="Search-In-Modal-1" type="search" name="q" value="" placeholder="Search" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="predictive-search-results-list" aria-controls="predictive-search-results-list" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-autocomplete="list" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false">
                                <label class="field__label" for="Search-In-Modal-1">Search</label>
                                <input type="hidden" name="options[prefix]" value="last">
                                <button class="search__button field__button" aria-label="Search">
                                    <!--<svg class="icon icon-search" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation">
                                                  <use href="#icon-search">
                                                </svg>-->
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="icon icon-search">
                                        <path d="M22.938 13.382c-0.036 5.247-4.318 9.472-9.565 9.437s-9.472-4.318-9.436-9.565c0.035-5.223 4.28-9.438 9.503-9.437 5.263 0.023 9.513 4.302 9.501 9.565h-0.003zM26.881 13.382c-0.032-7.423-6.075-13.414-13.498-13.382s-13.414 6.075-13.382 13.497c0.031 7.4 6.039 13.382 13.44 13.382 7.435-0.025 13.447-6.062 13.44-13.498z"></path>
                                        <path d="M29.216 31.882l-8.499-8.451 2.784-2.787 8.499 8.451-2.784 2.787z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="predictive-search predictive-search--header" tabindex="-1" data-predictive-search>
                                <div class="predictive-search__loading-state">
                                    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="spinner" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                        <circle class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="6" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle>
                                    </svg>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <span class="predictive-search-status visually-hidden" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </form>
                    </predictive-search>
                </div>
                <div class="search-backdrop"></div>
```